# Convert very big .csv file to .xls without cutting rows of data

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I was using this code to convert .csv files to .xls files. It is working good for the smaller .csv files, but when I want to convert big .csv files with 100 000 rows of data, this code cuts around 35k rows of data, so I end up with .xls file with around 65k rows of data.

```
Sub CSVtoXLS()

    Dim xFd As FileDialog
    Dim xSPath As String
    Dim xCSVFile As String
    Dim xWsheet As String
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.StatusBar = True
    xWsheet = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Set xFd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xFd.Title = "Select a folder:"
    If xFd.Show = -1 Then
        xSPath = xFd.SelectedItems(1)
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Right(xSPath, 1) <> "\" Then xSPath = xSPath + "\"
    xCSVFile = Dir(xSPath & "*.csv")
    Do While xCSVFile <> ""
        Application.StatusBar = "Converting: " & xCSVFile
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=xSPath & xCSVFile
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Replace(xSPath & xCSVFile, ".csv", ".xls", vbTextCompare), xlNormal
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        Windows(xWsheet).Activate
        xCSVFile = Dir
    Loop
    Application.StatusBar = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

I think this is happening because VBA is not waiting for CSV files to fully open. When I am manually opening these .csv files I always have to wait few seconds/minutes because they are so big.
Is there a way I can tell VBA to wait until .csv file is fully opened and then to proceed with code execution?

Maybe file size is not problem, maybe something else is problem? Is there a way to convert .csv file to .xls without opening it?

Can you help me somehow to solve it?

---

To me it is not important if the file extension is .xls or .xlsx.

So, I tried to change this part of the code: `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Replace(xSPath & xCSVFile, ".csv", ".xls", vbTextCompare), xlNormal` to `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Replace(xSPath & xCSVFile, ".csv", ".xlsx", vbTextCompare), xlNormal`.

But now I can't open .xlsx files. I am getting the message:

[image: error]

Maybe the code it self is not good?

Comment: xls is the legacy file format - is there a reason you're not using xls*x* which has been supported since Excel 2007, and supports more than 65,535 rows of data ?

Comment: To me it is not important if the file extension is .xls or .xlsx.

So, I tried to change this part of the code:

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Replace(xSPath & xCSVFile, ".csv", **".xls"**, vbTextCompare), xlNormal

to 

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Replace(xSPath & xCSVFile, ".csv", **".xlsx"**, vbTextCompare), xlNormal

But now I can't open .xlsx files. I am getting the message [error message][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SD67x.png


Maybe the code it self is not good?

Comment: Try replacing `xlNormal` with `xlOpenXMLWorkbook`.

Comment: @Domenic - Please post as an answer.

Comment: @Enigmativity I have posted an answer, as per your request.

Comment: @Domenic - And I've already upvoted. The OP should now mark as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

The file format for an `xlsx` workbook is `xlOpenXMLWorkbook`.  Therefore try the following instead...

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Replace(xSPath & xCSVFile, ".csv", ".xlsx", vbTextCompare), xlOpenXMLWorkbook
```